# Cannot Run Registry Record in RunOnce because of VMWare Tools installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, vmware

I am trying to test an unattended installation of windows in a vmware machine.

I have a registry record in Local Machine RunOnce.. which points to a batch file

As soon as windows starting.. vmware tools are installed and afterwards nothing my batch file is not running.. and the record in registry of RunOnce is deleted..

So how to disable maybe vmware tools installation

or

How to put a delay in vmware installation and start installation after batch file ( which installs MSOffice2007)

thank you

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your batch file is not running at all?  It seems very unlikely to me that VMware Tools would disrupt RunOnce keys in the registry.  Instead, I suspect what's happening is your script ends up trying to install Office while the VMware Tools installer is running, causing it to fail. (Typically only one installation process can be running at a time.) In that case, I would recommend that you adjust your script to wait until other installation processes are done.

Comment: And if you really want to disable VMware Tools installation, note that VMware Tools aren't just magically installed on their own.  You need to explicitly request that VMware (Workstation? Player? You haven't specified what product you're using) install them, *or* you need choose to use Easy Install when creating the VM.